# About divergence theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Consider the portion $S$ of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ with $z\ge -1$. Calculate the integral $$\iint_{S} (x^3, y^3, z^3)\cdot \vec{n} dS$$

a) Using directly a parametrization

Well, what are the steps that I need to follow to parametrize this? Can I use spherical coordinates?

Comment: You definitely want to use spherical coordinates as the limits of integration will be rather tricky otherwise. Think about a trig relation to get the limits of integration for your angle measured from $z$ (I'm not sure if you personally use $\phi$ or $\theta$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\nabla{\langle{x^3,y^3,z^3}\rangle}&=3x^2+3y^2+3z^2 \\
x&=\rho \sin(\phi)\cos(\theta) \\
y&=\rho \sin(\phi)\sin(\theta) \\
z&=\rho \cos(\phi) \\
3\rho^2&=3\rho^2\sin^2(\phi)\cos^2(\theta)+3\rho^2\sin^2(\phi)\sin^2(\theta)+3\rho^2\cos^2(\phi) \end{align}$$

Now find the limit of integration and take the integral:

$$\begin{align}
-1&=2\cos(\phi) \\
\phi&=\frac{2}{3}\pi \\
\iint_{S} (x^3, y^3, z^3)\cdot \vec{n} dS&=\int_0^{\frac{2}{3}\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^23\rho^4\sin(\phi)d\rho\space{d\theta}\space{d\phi}
\end{align}$$